# JBoss/MAT analysis complains about org.jboss.vfs.spi.javaZipFileSystem

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Using JBoss 6.4 EAP. Have been having memory problems lately. Lot's of GC.
Got a heap dump with jmap. jmap got a hprof file 2GB large, but I'm pretty sure it's using 4GB, because of the GC logs.
Inside MAT, it complains in "Leak Suspects" that 1.2 GB is associated with org.jboss.vfs.spi.javaZipFileSystem. It says:

16345 instances of "org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem", loaded by "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0x3e81nnnn occupy 1,283,825,460 (56.91%) byte. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]", loaded by ""

I have followed several trails, but no good explanation. Any clues?

Comment: I have managed to discover that the vfs directory has 16K directories, with many of them duplicates... They mostly have JARs inside. Seems it might be a packaging issue. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for the question. Were you able to fix the issue ? I am having the same issue. Could you please share your solution?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342907/memory-leak-due-to-more-number-of-instances-of-org-jboss-vfs-spi-javazipfilesyst

Comment: No, unfortunately not...