# Memory leak due to more number of instances of org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jboss, eclipse-memory-analyzer

We are using JBoss eap 6.4. We are running into heap issues(out f memory error) when the application is deployed and accessed.Created a heap dump file to investigate more. Analyzed the heap dump file using Eclipse MAT tool. MAT tool is complaining abut the following leak.

> Problem Suspect 1
>
> 183 instances of "org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem", loaded by
>   "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0xe0884088" occupy 24,507,432
>   (14.20%) bytes.
>
> Biggest instances: •org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem @ 0xe1c65988 -
>   2,367,616 (1.37%) bytes.  •org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem @
>   0xe1c64308 - 1,883,528 (1.09%) bytes. 
>   •org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem @ 0xe1c5c660 - 1,729,400 (1.00%)
>   bytes.  These instances are referenced from one instance of
>   "java.util.HashMap$Node[]", loaded by ""
>
> Keywords org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem java.util.HashMap$Node[]
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0xe0884088
>
> Details »

Can anyone explain the above leak(why it happens and what cane be done?)and propose a solution to fix the memory leak?

> UPDATE:
>   The following is the list of classes that the JBOSS is trying to load:
>   [image]

**UPDATE:**
The following is the dominator tree view using Eclipse MAT: 
[image]

The following is the path to GC of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory(This class has more retained heap):

[image]

Comment: That's just the JBoss classloader unzipping archives and loading classes, can you find out what classes it was trying to load?

Comment: @xtratic , Sorry for the delayed response. I have attached the screenprint to the question that shows the classes that JBOSS is trying to load. Any clue on how to proceed further now?

Comment: What I mean is that `org.jboss.vfs...` (virtual file system) is looking through your file system and trying to load classes, etc. Perhaps the root directory of your VFS has too much scope and so it is looking through a ton of files that it shouldn't be. Please check what is the root file of your VFS?

Comment: Also from reading other threads related to this, it looks like lowering `maxThreads` here `/opt/pvo/cots/jboss/server/all.pvo/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml` may help.

Comment: @xtratic, The root directory of vfs is my war file name and it has few more directories inside it and there by several java, html, xml files etc exists. Please let me know if I provided the expected information. Any clue now?  I will try by lowering the `maxThreads` in `server.xml`. I am just curious how it is going to solve the problem?

Comment: Well the issue certainly seems to be *something* to do with running out of memory while the VFS is loading resources: either trying to load too much, or too fast, or a combination of the two; You're verifying the scope of what it's loading to make sure it's not loading too much, and you're lowering the number of threads to try to make it not load as fast.

Comment: Can you provide the exact libraries and versions so that I can try to trace your issue? I think the sources I had found are not actually helpful.

Comment: @xtratic, I have added the dominator tree view of the heap dump and  path to GC of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory(This class has more retained heap) to the question. Could you please look at it?

Comment: which version you're using? 6.4.22? this issue was fixed in 6.4.5 I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It Looks simular to known jboss EAP issue described in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/36954
The link is for EAP version 5 but looks like 6 has similar issue. The class name may be different.

A workaround is to reduce the number of deployed jars:

- [Slim EAP 5](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/36954).
- For applications that use the same library version, move any duplicate jars amongst deployments to $JBOSS_HOME/server/$CONFIG/lib/.
- use unzipped deployments
- use the below JVM option to re-order in-memory JAR handling to reduce VFS cache memory consumption at potential performance hit:

  -Djboss.vfs.optimizeForMemory=true

**Diagnostic steps:**

Check what JAR entries there are using the OQL statement below. Lots of duplication here will show you were the retention is stemming from.

```
SELECT toString(s.rootURI.string) FROM org.jboss.virtual.plugins.context.zip.ZipEntryContext s
```

in your case

```
SELECT toString(s.rootURI.string) FROM org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem s
```